# express в чем отличие маршрутизации с использованием app и route?

Tags: express

Читаю документацию
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

там написано что бывает
Application-level middleware и
Router-level middleware

Но из приведенных примеров я не понял в чем отличие Application-level middleware от
Router-level middleware ?

Исходя из примеров кода вместо app просто используется router. - а код один и тот же (за исключением next('router') вместо next('route'))

В каких случаях для обработки маршрутов надо использовать app - а в каких router ?

Comment: [Router-level middleware works in the same way as application-level middleware, except it is bound to an instance of express.Router().](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Grundy, спасибо за комментарий, но в каких случаях может понадобиться router ? Зачем введена эта сущность ?

Answer (score 0):

ответ на свой вопрос я нашел в английской версии SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227650/difference-between-app-use-and-router-use-in-express

а также в документации:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Объект router представляет собой изолированный экземпляр middleware и routes.
Можно сказать что router представляет собой мини приложение предназначенное для исполнения функций middleware и роутинга.

```
// this will only be invoked if the path starts with /bar from the mount point
router.use('/bar', function (req, res, next) {
  // ... maybe some additional /bar logging ...
  next()
})

app.use('/foo', router)
```

В данном случае router монтируется начиная с пути /foo
Т.е. функция, определенная в router вызывается по пути /foo/bar

При этом путь "/foo" удаляется и не виден внутри middleware, определенного в router.